# Does HttpPostedFileBase contentlength mean the actual traffic used to upload a file?

Tags: asp.net, webp

I am trying to upload an image to a windows server. I find that the HttpPostedFileBase contentlength is much larger than the actual size of the original image.

My question is which number is the actual traffic amount used for uploading the image, the original size or the contengLength?

Answer (score 0):

The `ContentLength` property which you are seeing in `HttpPostedFileBase` class contains the `number of bytes` in the posted file.

`int counts = file.contentlength`